# Check orientation in AwakeFromNib – Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to check the orientation of the iphone in the AwakeFromNib method. This is my code:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarOrientation];

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        NSLog(@"orientation portrait");
    }    
    else if (orientation == (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
    {
        NSLog(@"Orientation landscape");
    }
}
```

The logs aren't messaged when I'm turning my iPhone, what's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using breakpoints to see what the value of orientation is?

Answer (score 0):

Your comments on Michael Dautermann's (now-deleted) answer are contradictory.  You said you're creating your view programmatically, but you also talked about “when the view is loaded”.

Either you're creating the view in code, **or** you're loading it from a nib/storyboard.  You can't be doing both with the same view instance.

The fact that your `awakeFromNib` method isn't being called matches your claim that you are creating the view programmatically.  But another possibility is that you **are** loading the view from a nib but have not correctly set the “Custom Class” of the view in the nib, so it's not actually creating an instance of your view subclass.

If you **are** truly creating the view programmatically, then somewhere you should have code like this:

```
view = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:someRect];
```

or maybe this:

```
view = [[MyView alloc] init];
```

The second case, under the covers, just calls `[self initWithFrame:CGRectZero]`.  So either way, your view's `initWithFrame:` method is getting called.  So you should override that method and check the interface orientation there.

If you're not creating the view in one of those ways, then edit your question to explain exactly how you **are** creating it.